# Adding structs to an array and changing their attributes

Tags: c, arrays, struct

```
    int numOfProcesses = 0;
printf("How many processes would you like to enter: ");
scanf("%d",&numOfProcesses);
struct process p[numOfProcesses];
int counter = 1;
// This is the quantum printf(argv[1]);
// This is the type to run printf(argv[2]);
if(argv[2] = "FCFS"){
  while(counter < numOfProcesses){
    int temp;
    p[counter];
    printf("For process %d: \n",counter);
    printf("Enter the pid: ");
    scanf("%d", p[counter].pid);
    printf("Enter the burst time: ");
    scanf("%d",p[counter].burstTime);
    printf("Enter the arrival time: ");
    scanf("%d",p[counter].arrivalTime);

    counter++;
  }
```

I am trying to get my code to hold an array of structs and allow me to edit the attributes of the structs in the array but everything keeps resulting in a seg fault. What am I doing worng?

Comment: `scanf("%d", p[counter].pid);` -> `scanf("%d", &p[counter].pid);`.  Same for the next two.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: `if(argv[2] = "FCFS"){` **-->>** `if(!strcmp(argv[2] , "FCFS")){`

Comment: `p[counter];` does nothing.

Comment: You are starting at 1, but arrays start at 0.

Comment: Turn on verbose warnings of your compiler, you should get messages about all these problems.

Comment: To turn on compiler warnings with gcc/clang add (at minimum) `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to your compiler options. For VS, e.g. `cl.exe`, add `/W3` -- and do not accept code until it compiles without a single warning. That alone will go far to end your suffering... (that and... *Validate Every Single User Input...*)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing mulitple issues in the code:

1. if(argv[2] = "FCFS")

A. I assume the objective is to compare things. It has to be "==" instead of "=". But again that doesn't work for strings

B. For strings, you have to write it as if(!strcmp(argv[2], "FCFS")

2. The line p[counter]; is not needed. It does not have any action.
3. Counter has to be initialized to 0 instead of 1
4. I am not sure of the members of struct process, but I am assuming they are all integers. In scanf you have to pass the address of the members

scanf("%d", &p[counter].pid);

scanf("%d", &p[counter].burstTime);

scanf("%d", &p[counter].arrivalTime);

If they are pointers to integers, then also segmentation fault will occur since they are not initialized anywhere in the code